# @ngrx effects prevent switchmap break on error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have 3 http calls during the sign up process: signup with auth provider, create account within api, then login.

If signup with auth provider fails (say account already exists), it still attempts to create the account within the api.
If I add a catch at the end of the @Effect, the second attempt (say a corrected credentials) will no longer invoke the effect.

How can I prevent the subsequent (accountSercice.CreateAccount and authenticationService.Login) switchMaps from running?

```
@Effect() AccountSigningUp$ = this.actions$
.ofType(ACCOUNT_SIGNING_UP)
.map((action: AccountActions.AccountSigningUp) => action.payload)
.switchMap(signUpModel => this.authenticationService.SignUp(signUpModel)
    .catch(err => {
        let signUpModel = new SignUpModel();
        signUpModel.message = err;
        return Observable.of(new AccountSignUpFailed(signUpModel))
    })
    .switchMap(signUpModel => this.accountService.CreateAccount((signUpModel as SignUpModel))
        .catch(err => {
            let signUpModel = new SignUpModel();
            signUpModel.message = err;
            return Observable.of(new AccountSignUpFailed(signUpModel))
        })
    )
    .switchMap(loginModel => this.authenticationService.Login((loginModel as LoginModel))
        .map(tokenModel => {
            this.tokenService.Save(tokenModel);
            return new AccountLoggedIn();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            let loginModel = new LoginModel();
            loginModel.message = err;
            return Observable.of(new AccountLoginFailed(loginModel))
        })
    )
    .map(() => new AccountCreated())
);
```

Comment: FYI returning `Observable.of(...)` from the catch operator is just like a standard `try/catch` where the code will continue after the catch (in this case the stream). Returning `Observable.throw(...)` from the catch operator is like re-throwing an error inside a `try/catch` where it will bubble up till it is caught (in this case skip all other operators in the stream till it hits a catch or the error callback on subscribe). I just share that for your understanding. The right answer is already proposed (setup separate effects that trigger off of the success of each-other).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create three different Effects for this scenario. And Call Another effect when first completes. Something like this -

```
/**
* Effect For Auth service
*/
@Effect() authenticationService$ = this.actions$
.ofType(AUTH_SERVICE)
.map((action: AccountActions.AccountSigningUp) => action.payload)
.switchMap(signUpModel => this.authenticationService.SignUp(signUpModel)
.map(res =>({ type: action.CREATE_ACCOUNT, payload: res.json()}))
.catch(() => Observable.of({ type: action.AUTH_SERVICE_FAILED }))
)




/**
    * Effect For Create Account service
    */
    @Effect() authenticationService$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(CREATE_ACCOUNT)
    .map((action: AccountActions.AccountSigningUp) => action.payload)
    .switchMap(signUpModel => this.accountService.CreateAccount((signUpModel as SignUpModel))
    .map(res =>({ type: action.LOGIN, payload: res.json()}))
    .catch(() => Observable.of({ type: action.CREATE_ACCOUNT_FAILED }))
    )

    /**
    * Effect For Login service
    */
    @Effect() authenticationService$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(LOGIN)
    .map((action: AccountActions.AccountSigningUp) => action.payload)
    .switchMap(signUpModel => this.authenticationService.Login((loginModel as LoginModel))
    .map(res =>({ type: action.LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: res.json()}))
    .catch(() => Observable.of({ type: action.LOGIN_FAILED }))
    )
```

in Case if you want to call two actions in your success call, you can use mergeMap like this.

```
@Effect() authenticationService$ = this.actions$
.ofType(LOGIN)
.map((action: AccountActions.AccountSigningUp) => action.payload)
.switchMap(signUpModel => this.authenticationService.Login((loginModel 
 as LoginModel))
.mergeMap((response) =>            
 return[
     ({ type: action.FIRST_ACTION, payload: response.json() }),
     ({ type: action.SECOND_ACTION, payload: response.json()})
      ];
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for tour suggestion. I do have an effect for logging in, however for some reason it was not being called, hence why I have the code the to login. I can try again

Comment: Thanks, I followed that and it now works. However, it is not 100% yet, as the CREATE_ACCOUNT needs to fire two actions: LOGIN and ACCOUNT_CREATED. Any ideas how do achieve this?

Comment: You can use mergeMap after your service call. It basically returns an array of actions.

Comment: @WPalombini i have updated the code, i hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply. I did try it but it seems that it does not respect the order. The signup page is subscribed to the ACCOUNT_CREATED action, which then redirects the user. It is attempting to redirect the user, however login has not finished yet, which causes error related to not being authenticated. Is there a way to make the actions run in order?

Comment: You can Use forkJoin operator. it accepts an array of Observable and waits for them to finish. check out this link https://gist.github.com/peterbsmith2/ce94c0a5ddceb99bab24a761731d1f07